# find id of user with JWT token in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, jwt, postman

In my API after the user registers, a token is created with this code :

`$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);`

when i use dd($token) , returns this :

`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMFwvYXBpXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTYyNjgxNDM2NCwiZXhwIjoxNjI2ODE3OTY0LCJuYmYiOjE2MjY4MTQzNjQsImp0aSI6Imd3eDZnVzNGTGN4MzlMekIiLCJzdWIiOjQsInBydiI6IjIzYmQ1Yzg5NDlmNjAwYWRiMzllNzAxYzQwMDg3MmRiN2E1OTc2ZjcifQ._m-7tojFaupUbAibDUbLJm6BeuFVL_etdFlwj0h5664`

so how can i find the id of user without entering this token in authorization of postman ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use https://jwt.io

In "sub" (subject) you will see the user id.

[image]

Read more about [jwt tokens](https://jwt.io/introduction)

Answer (score 0):

whatever token string you get from request headers, use that to create an object of `Token` class like this

`$token = new Token(token_string);`

After, use that `$token` inside of `JWTAuth` class like this

`JWTAuth::setToken($token);`

Finally call `getPayload` method of `JWTAuth` class to get actual data.

`JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->get('sub')`

Full code

```
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Token;
...
...

// generate token
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$tokenString = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

// decode token to get actual data
$token = new Token($tokenString); // here you use header insted of $tokenString
JWTAuth::setToken($token);
$subject = JWTAuth::getPayload($token)->get('sub');
```

Comment: But, he already have a user model with user_id :)